# What photography magazines exist for professionals?

Tags: learning

I am searching photography magazines (without judging which one is better/worse) which:

- Target professionals (no or very little of "beginner tips")
- Are not oriented towards post-processing (no or very little "Photoshop" advice)
- Focus on photography rather than on photographic equipment
- Available in a paper version

(I am well aware that above criteria are fuzzy and can be perceived as subjective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What country are you based in? Photography magazines available in print are often country-specific. In the UK there are magazines like `Professional Photographer`, but I also read `Black And White Photography`, which in my opinion meets the criteria you specify, although whether it's specifically targeting professionals I am not sure.

Edit: a further quick check on WH Smith website for magazine subscriptions available also shows the following magazines that i would imagine are suited to professionals:

- Professional Photography
- British Journal of Photography
- Photo Professional

Comment: it's France, but searching for  magazines in english

Comment: @ts. My suggestions may be your best bet, delivery to france from the UK shouldn't be too expensive

Comment: @ts. I've added 3 more I've found

Answer (score 2):

Canon produces a quarterly Magazine that is distributed to it's Canon Pro Services (CPS) members, titled; CPN Canon Professional Network.

If you are a Canon User with a minimum of 2 x Pro Bodies(40D or above) and 3 x L Lenses, you can join CPS Silver service by registering and listing these on the Canon CPS online portal

The Magazine is a mixture of articles from Pro Shooters providing anecdotal references and experiences as well as sections on tips, tech solutions, commercials and brand marketing techniques etc.

I believe Nikon also produces a Tri-yearly magazine called Nikon Pro.

Please do take into account, I live and work in UK and Europe and therefore, cannot guarantee that the CPN magazine is available outside of this region. There may also be an annual cost for different countries and different tiers. There is no current charge for it in the UK.

Comment: I don't believe those are the current CPS Silver membership requirements. It is based on points now and for Silver you need 10 points. You could easily get that with 1 body and 1 lens for example. See http://cps.usa.canon.com/about_cps/about.shtml

Comment: @dpollitt but not in the UK by the looks of it

Comment: It also appears in Canada they don't have the point system

Comment: You are all correct, the CPN mag seems to be different for different regions. The link for UK and Europe seems to be the following link with a requirement for camera and lens count http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/services.do

Answer (score 0):

[Photo Life](https://www.photolife.com/), published out of Quebec City, is an English language magazine with a focus on technique, artistry, and managing a photog biz.

There are the usual tutorials and gear reviews, as well.